# Packaging (archiving) Python project on Linux

Tags: python, linux, python-module

I have a Python project with various Python modules. Now, when I need to set the project to another server (Linux OS), I have also set up each module, which are important to the project.

My question is: how can I package (or archivate) module dependencies and projects set to another server with just unpackage (or unzip) and etc.?

**UPDATE:** Finally I use cx_Freeze, which work fine for my project. But guys gave really useful advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python has a nice way to deal with projects and dependencies: [Virtual Environments](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv).

An interesting article:

- http://www.logilab.org/blogentry/22498

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of virtual environments (not necessary if you do not want it) and pip. You can give pip a file with all your dependencies like so:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

For more information on how to create this requirements.txt please see http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/requirements.html
More information on the virtualenv is here http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/